# High level of Vitamin D,1,25(OH)2, Total

Tags: micronutrients, blood-tests

I recently got blood test results and they say

```
Normal Range, High level of Vitamin D,1,25(OH)2, Total = 18 - 72 pg/mL
```

but my level is

```
96
```

I was researching this and found that it can be due to supplements, but I am not taking supplements with Vitamin D.

I stay indoors a lot, except to commute to work via public transportation.

I am unable to find out what else can cause high level of Vitamin D.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be linked to your diet, but Vitamin D is not found in many foods (with the exception of fish and fortified foods). However, there have been some reports that laboratories may be producing an incorrect value.

"This means that compared with the actual concentration of 25(OH)D in a sample of blood serum, a falsely low or falsely high value may be obtained depending on the assay or laboratory used."

Follow this link on a list of foods high in Vitamin D and some other facts: https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminD-HealthProfessional/

Comment: How do which know which reports are correct. This is life and death for many tests.

Comment: You can contact the laboratory to distinguish the testing method used at that facility. A great practice in any field is to get a second opinion. Get your testing done at another lab and compare your results.

Comment: I just might go ahead and do that. I mean, I feel totally fine, and I don't have any symptoms of toxic vitamin D, i.e. nausea, etc